# Data lookup speed verses system memory

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory

I have an application that processes scanning transactions from hand held terminals in a warehouse.  Each scan (of which there can be hundreds of thousands throughout a day) has to lookup a pick location (again of which there can be hundreds of thousands) to find its’ physical location.  In order to get the speed of processing I require I pull the entire list of locations into a dictionary so it’s in RAM but naturally this has an impact on the system memory and I’m getting ‘system out of memory’ errors every few days (the system runs constantly on a virtual server).  My questions then are: is my approach sensible?  Is this (as I believe) the fastest method for accessing the data once in the system?  Are there any ideas for helping with the memory issue?

```
For x = 1 To MapBindingSource.Count
    Dim B As New Bin
    B.LocationID = MapBindingSource.Current("LocationID")
    B.x = MapBindingSource.Current("X")
    B.y = MapBindingSource.Current("Y")
    B.z = MapBindingSource.Current("Z")
    'etc...    

        Try
            BinDictionary.Add(B.LocationID, B)
        Catch ex As Exception
            msgbox("Error message here")
        End Try

     MapBindingSource.MoveNext()
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Sensible is a matter of opinion which depends entirely on the circumstances (e.g. how much data, how powerful is the hardware, how fast does it need to be, what is the format of the data).  The `Dictionary` uses a hash table to index the data.  Whether that is the *fastest* data structure to use all depends on the data and how often, if ever, it changes.  There plenty of other popular data structures which may be better--some built into .NET (e.g. `HashSet`, `SortedList`, `SortedDictionary`) and many which aren't.  But that's a very broad topic.

The most common way to solve this is to use a good database engine with a properly tuned database.  In most cases, a database should get almost as good performance, since it would index everything using the best data structures for the job and it would cache everything in memory efficiently.  Not only would it handle all that work for you, but it would also add more features which you could make use of in the future.  If you are already using a database, I would suggest trying other engines and configurations because it *shouldn't* be that slow.

As far as running out of memory goes, the simplest answer is to say that shouldn't be an issue if you change your process to 64-bit.  When an application runs as a 32-bit process, it is limited to 2GB or memory (and when you factor in overhead and fragmentation, it's usually closer to 1.5GB).  When it runs as 64-bit, it gets a much much larger memory space, almost certainly larger than the physical RAM and virtual memory on the machine, so then you are only limited by the amount of hardware you want to throw at it.  However, the way you described the situation sounds suspect.  If you load all the data into memory at start-up, and that's what's causing you to run out of memory, it should fail with an out of memory exception right away.  If it doesn't fail for a day or two, you probably have a memory leak in your application.  If that's the case, switching to 64-bit will make it run longer, but only delays the inevitable.

Comment: Very helpful response …. The data in the location list will (almost) never change.  The underlying data for the application is in Access files and I guess it has always just been an assumption on my part that to access the DB file would be less efficiency (it didn't occur to me that they would cache).  Also I hadn't considered switching to 64 bit which could be a solution.  I'm sure you are right to be suspicious about my code being leaky... I need to read up more on how to deal with this.  Thankyou for your thoughtful reply.

Comment: If you're currently using Access, try giving SQL Server Express a try.